# cant import win32print on odoo 8 Windows

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, python-import, pywin32

I am trying to use the win32print operations on pos models and am getting error while running. which shows unable to import win32print. does I need to do anything extra configurations to import third party packages?

What I have tried:
here i tried to print the file, but its simply will work if the win32printer is imported correctly. because in console it works fine.

```
import sys
from openerp.osv import osv
import logging
import win32print

class PrintNetwork(osv.osv):
    _name = 'printer.network'

    def print_network_printer(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        print ("-----------------------------------------------------", sys.path)
        main(name, "test data")
        return sys.path


class PrinterError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message


class WindowsPrinter(object):
    def __init__(self, printer):
        self.printer = self.get_printer(printer)

    def get_printer(self, name):
        return win32print.OpenPrinter(name)

def main(printer_name, data):
    printer = WindowsPrinter(printer_name)
```

The log says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi

  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 165, in execute

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\service\server.py", line 295, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\http.py", line 1297, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\http.py", line 1435, in dispatch
    ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\http.py", line 353, in registry
    return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 339, in get
    update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 351, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 143, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\module.py", line 315, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\module.py", line 80, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\addons\point_of_sale\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import print_network
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\addons\point_of_sale\print_network.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .. import win32print
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\modules\module.py", line 79, in load_module
    f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named win32print
```

Comment: Never worked with _Odoo_, but the error: `File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170309\server\openerp\addons\point_of_sale\print_network.py", line 12, in <module>`, `from .. import win32print` seems strange (the `import`). However, looking at [\[GitHub\]: (__8.0__) odoo/addons/point_of_sale](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/point_of_sale), there's no _print\_network.py_.